# Getting User Profile fields using PeopleManager gives Field Not Initialized

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to access basic user profile fields like displayName and eventually my own custom profile fields.  I am able to access and list out the users in the site but when I try to access a single field, I get the following error message.  Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Environment: Sharepoint Online
Code: Javascript

Error Message: "

> The property or field 'DisplayName' has not been initialized. It has
>   not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need
>   to be explicitly requested."

Code Sample:

```
function onGetAllUsersSucceeded()
{   
    var enumerator = allUsers.getEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var currUser = enumerator.get_current();
        personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(currUser.get_loginName());
        context.load(personProperties);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSyncOneUser,onFail);
    }
}

function onSyncOneUser()
{
    if(personProperties !== null)
    {
        writeResult("User Properties Loaded");
        writeResult(personProperties.get_displayName());
    }
}
```

*I am able to get to the point where the result says 'User Properties Loaded' but then it says displayName is not initialized when it hits the next line.

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you trying to return User Profile properties for just the currently logged in user or multiple users?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the display name  in your context.load event.

```
context.load(personProperties, 'Include(DisplayName)')
```

Certain properties are not brought through, this ensures they are included in the call.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing your operation after the `SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager` loads.

Refer below sample snippet for loading user profile properties:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', YourFunctionName);
```

Read full article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj667813(v=office.15).aspx).

Hope this helps!